# Unresolved import:" execute_from_command_line occured when I worked with the pydev in Eclipse"

Tags: import, pydev

Win7 64 bit + Eclipse Indigo + Pydev.
The Unresolved import: "execute_from_command_line occured" in the file manage.py of the Django project.
I have add all django folder path to the PythonPath and I can use the statement:"from django.db import models" with out errors.How should I do,give me some help.

Comment: The error happens in runtime or that's an error shown by the editor? (it'd be nice if you added the actual import you're using to have the error, not only the error line).

Comment: The software you used to translate your question comes across as rude. That explains why you didn't get any help. I wish I could help you though, I am having the same problem.